# words break inside a DIV

Tags: html, css

I am just like this guy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430641/word-break-issue-in-css

I am experiencing everything he said, I also tried all sort of things, but unfortunately nothing helped.

That question didn't have a helpful answer. So, I am posting it again.

I am using codeigniter and this is how I echo my paragraph:

```
<div class="review-content">

  <p><?php echo $review->content ; ?></p>

</div>
```

The output would like this:

```
 A very clean hotel with a great st
 aff and very helpful. The restaura
 nt is classic but the food is very
```

Comment: It's doing that because word-wrap:break-word is being used in your CSS. Change that to normal to stop it wrapping words. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `word-break`

```
div {
    width: 210px;
    word-break: break-all; /* this is probably set somewhere in your code */
    background: #f5f5f5;
}

div.no-break {
    word-break: normal;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r8Akx/)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `word-wrap` property. Setting it to `word-wrap:break-word` should be what you're looking for.

For more info, [the MDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap).